# passing string to an external assembly function

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to learn some assembly. 
My goal is to create an external assembly function that is able to read an array of char, cast to int and then execute various operation, just to learn something.

I've done many proofs but i think i'm missing the point

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

extern int foo(char array[]);

int main(void){
    char array[SIZE]={'0','1','1','0','1'};
    printf("GAS said: %c\n", foo(array));

    return 0;
}
```

assembly:

```
.data

.text
    .global foo

foo:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%esp), %eax #saving in eax the pointer of the array
    movl (%eax), %eax #saving in eax the first char of the array

    popl %ebp
    ret
```

The strange thing for me is here: 
when i use, like in this case

```
printf("GAS said: %c\n", foo(array));
```

The output is, as expected, GAS said: 0

Based on this, i was expecting also that changing with:

```
printf("GAS said: %i\n", foo(array));
```

will output GAS said: 48 but instead i get in return some random address.

Also, in the assembly file, i can't explain why if i try to

```
cmpl $48, %eax
je LABEL
```

the jump will never happen.

The only thing i can think of is that there is a problem with the size, since int takes 4B and char only 1B but i'm not so sure.

So, how can i use compare and return an int to main in this case?

Comment: `movl (%eax), %eax` moves the 4 bytes at address in EAX to the register EAX, not just one character. If you want to use all of EAX to hold a character you can do `movzxb (%eax), %eax` which will move a byte and zero extend it across the 32-bit register EAX.

Comment: Alternatively you can do `movb (%eax), %al` which moves a singly byte to the register AL (AL is the low byte of EAX). But then you'd need to compare just the value AL and not the whole 32-bit register EAX

Comment: The code you are writing is 32-bit so I hope you aren't compiling and assembling as 64-bit code.

Comment: I'm using a 64-bit machine but i use as option --32 and gcc -m32 in order to assembly 32-bit code. Thanks for your suggestion! Now all works fine